# Where are the nonreal zero's of $\zeta(s) - \zeta(s + 1) + \zeta(s + 2) $ ??

Tags: examples-counterexamples, special-functions, zeta-functions

Let $\zeta(s)$ be the Riemann Zeta function.

Define the function $f(s) = \zeta(s) - \zeta(s+1) + \zeta(s+2)$

I know $f(s)$ is defined on the whole complex plane and has a simple pole at $-1$, $0$ and at $1$ and no other poles.

I also know the function $f(z)$ has infinitely many zero's on the negative real line.

I wonder where are the nonreal zero's of $\zeta(s) - \zeta(s + 1) + \zeta(s + 2) $ ??

$$\zeta(s) - \zeta(s + 1) + \zeta(s + 2) = 0 $$

I found $ s = -5.957 + 2.776 i$ and $ s = 0.380 + 0.770 i$ and their conjugates.

I did not find zero's with $Re(s) > 1/2 $ by hand. Do they exist ??

And how about zero's with $Re(s) > 1 $ ?

Is there a real number $a$ such that any zero satisfies $Re(s) < a $ ?

Can this be analyzed theoretically ( without computer search ) ?

Similar question for $g(s) = \zeta(s) - \zeta(s+1) + \zeta(s + \frac{5}{4})$

I found $0.193 + 0.541 i$ as solution to $g(s) = 0$.

Comment: 1) $f$ has a simple pole at $-1$ (where the $\zeta(s+2)=\zeta(1)$) as well
2) The zeta function has zeroes at negative even integers and in the critical stripe.  How do you know that $f$ has any zeroes on the real number line?

Comment: oh yes ofcourse at -1 too. I just forgot to type it. thanks Moko19.  Knowing there are infinitely many zero's on the negative real part comes from analyzing the zeta function there. For the case f : Since the trivial zero's are dense with gaps of 2, two of the zeta's are 0 infinitely often and this helps. For the case g : s+5/4 & s + 1 are "close enough ".  Im not saying it is trivial. Well maybe it is trivial but I do not see it and admit have not tried to construct a formal proof. Note the derivative of the zeta function at negative imput is key. Not sure if that helps. Im no expert afraid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer one of your questions: for $s=\sigma+it$ with $\sigma>1$, the bounds
$$
\frac{\zeta(2\sigma)}{\zeta(\sigma)} \le |\zeta(s)| \le \zeta(\sigma)
$$
are easy to verify from the Euler product for $\zeta(s)$. Therefore
$$
|f(s)| \ge \frac{\zeta(2\sigma)}{\zeta(\sigma)} - \zeta(\sigma+1) + \frac{\zeta(2(\sigma+2))}{\zeta(\sigma+2)}
$$
for $\sigma>1$, and the right-hand side is strictly positive for all $\sigma>1.4867$.

Comment: Intresting but Im a bit confused. Could you give more details plz ?